# Unable to Register Class TFMXApplicationDelegate

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I've read the Embarcadero and other docs, searched the net, and obviously something isn't sinking in. I have a significantly more complex Application and DLL/Dylib, but am now just using this simple example to try and get it to work. When I build the App and DLL for Win32 it works fine and it works fine if I do not make a function call to the DLL. As soon as I make a call to the DLL the error Unable to register Class TFMXApplicationDelegate is raised and the application terminates. This behaviour is the same whether the guest OS is on a VM (parallels) or a physical device (MacBook Pro 15 mid-2015).

QUESTION: How can I ensure that **TFMXApplicationDelegate** gets Registered, is there a setting or permission I need to set. It seems fairly basic since, according to the Apple documentation:

> The app delegate is effectively the root object of your app.

The DPR:

```
Library  pTestDLL;

uses
  uTestDLL in 'uTestDLL.pas';

{$R *.res}

end.
```

And here's the simple PAS file (for the Dylib):

```
unit uTestDLL;

interface

uses
  FMX.Dialogs;

// External functions and procedures
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; stdcall; forward;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
function _say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; cdecl; forward;
{$ENDIF MACOS}


exports
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  say_Hello;
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  _say_Hello;
  {$ENDIF MACOS}

Implementation

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; stdcall;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
function _say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; cdecl;
{$ENDIF MACOS}
begin
  Result := True;
  showmessage('In DLL: ' + Hello);
end;

end.
```

And lastly the simple test application:

```
unit uDylibTest1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;
const
  // Windows DLL Names
    {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    TestDLL = 'pTestDLL.dll';
    {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  // macOS DYLIB Names
    {$IFDEF MACOS}
    TestDLL = 'libpTestDLL.dylib';
    {$ENDIF MACOS}

type
  TfDylibTest = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TuDylibTest = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; stdcall; external TestDLL Delayed;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
function _say_Hello(Hello: string): boolean; cdecl; external TestDLL;
{$ENDIF MACOS}



var
  fDylibTest: TfDylibTest;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}


procedure TfDylibTest.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 b:boolean;

begin
  showmessage('B4 function call);
  b := False;
  // Call the DLL Function
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  b := say_Hello('The string passed to the DLL') then    
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  b :=  _say_Hello('The string passed to the DLL');     
  {$ENDIF MACOS}

  if b then
    showmessage('Say Hello OK')
  else
    showmessage('Say Hello Failed');
end;

procedure TfDylibTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('onCreate');
end;

procedure TfDylibTest.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('onShow');
end;

end.
```

Comment: No one. Not even a comment on how to ask the question better, rephrase the question etc etc. Surely someone has written a DYLIB in Delphi and had it work on macOS?

Comment: The only thing I can find on the web is this (XE2) comment from Delphi Haven (which doesn't help much:  ...This is more than can be said about using a FireMonkey dylib from a FireMonkey executable on the Mac, since it appears the two TApplication objects involved (one in the dylib, one in the executable) conflict – I get an exception from the dylib on load saying that the TApplicationDelegate class can’t be registered. ...

Comment: This one slipped past me, because it's not tagged with Delphi (I saw your post on G+, however). Do you have a callstack for when the error occurs?

Comment: @Dave Nottage, Yes my bad, I thought the Delphi-10.2-tokyo was appropriate. I've the project (test app/DLL-DYLIB) in a zip file. Is it possible to attach a file to the post? Not sure how...

Comment: You don't need to attach a project to show the callstack, i.e. what the debugger shows in the callstack window when the application throws the error

Comment: This is the call stack after the error (from the IDE):000e6fb8 ; bplrtl250
:000e7003 ; bplrtl250
:002c8133 ; bplrtl250
:002c8881 ; bplrtl250
:002c92d9 ; bplrtl250
:016417a7 ; bplfmx250
:0163ff10 ; bplfmx250
:000e7a7a ; bplrtl250
:000121a3 ; DyLibTest

Comment: @Dave Nottage Based on a suggestion from G+ (Alexander), I removed the show message lines from the DYLIB (work fine in DLL) and now the application and DYLIB actually work. I 'thought' I had taken out all of the show messages, but there was one that I just did not see - I could have looked at the code for a week and it was invisible. Anyway, it works, but I'd feel guilty putting forward the answer and taking credit. Is there some way I can put Alexander's response (from G+)  here and have him take the credit. Oh, and thanks for following it up Dave, I appreciate your interest and assistance.

Comment: I expect you'd need Alexander to come here and post his answer. That said, as long as the question remains on SO I guess others may find it and read the comments if they come up against the same issue :-)

Comment: You can write an answer to the question yourself so that future readers can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering tis on behalf of Alexander Brazda López who posted this on the G+ Delphi forum (so I'm not taking credit for someone else's answer):

> ShowMessage() use FMX.Dialogs inside a dll. I remember there were some
>   limitations about this and use bpl instead dll was recomended. I would
>   try to find some information about this. Just for check, try to use a
>   reversestring function for test open and calling dll functions its
>   working.

I cannot comment WRT the veracity of the next part of the response, but to be fair will include it. However the bottom line was that with FMX.Dialogs or FMX.Forms in the uses clause, I got the error. Remove those and the TFMXApplicationDelegate error did not occur.

In the non-trivial 'real' example, I was using the unit for `showmessage` and for `application.processmessages` which was in a cross platform function called `WaitNoFreeze()` which, as the name suggests, puts a wait in the main thread, but does not stop all other activity like `sleep()`.

> The problem is not that the dylib is not found, this can be checked by
>   calling a basic function in the dylib as function sum (a, b: integer):
>   integer
>
> The problem is when we invoke the UI through some function or use
>   embedded resources such as forms. This is because if we do not use
>   bpl, local instances are created instead of shared global instances,
>   this prevents functions such as RegisterClass or GetMem from sharing
>   the data. In the case of FMX there are differences due to the api for
>   the example that Kevin has exposed, in Windows the Handle of the
>   window is not necessary, so 0 is a valid value, in MacOSX it is
>   necessary but the value in the dynlib is NULL since it has not been
>   started, although in the application, but because the FMX instances
>   are not shared, it is not possible to access this information. It is
>   the same thing that happens when we try to free a block of memory in a
>   dll in windows that has been allocated by the application, that is why
>   we must use a bpl so that the memory manager of the application and
>   the dll is the same and maintain the same instances regardless of
>   whether their methods are invoked from the dll or from the exe